# ranges-v3 infinite range without iota

Tags: c++, gcc, range

I am trying to generate a set of CGAL random points using ranges-v3 library. For that, I use something like this:

```
    const std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<K>> mcSamplers =
        ranges::views::iota(0) |
        ranges::views::transform([&gen, &r0Generator, &r1Generator, &r2Generator](const auto i) {
            const auto r0 = r0Generator(gen);
            const auto r1 = r1Generator(gen);
            const auto r2 = r2Generator(gen);
            return CGAL::Point_3<K>(r0, r1, r2);
        }) | ranges::views::filter(
            [standardTetrahedron](const auto &p) { return standardTetrahedron.has_on_bounded_side(p); }) |
        ranges::views::take(10000) | ranges::to_vector;
```

This doesn't work with gcc because CGAL needs `-frounding-math` and some headers in `iota.h` has some `constexpr` which is not `constexpr` with that flag (`/usr/local/include/range/v3/iterator/diffmax_t.hpp:390:37: error: ‘(6.5e+1 * 3.0102999600000002e-1)’ is not a constant expression`)

Is there any other way to generate an infinite range which doesn't use `iota.h`?

Comment: This appears to be a bug. clang is fine with it, and there's no error on [gcc trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/achj3T), though it does give an error with GCC 10.2

Comment: Ill check. Thanks